# Java Swing - Making a scrollable JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have a custom component called FixtureComponent that extends JPanel, it is basically a JPanel containing a number of controls placed inside it, each with it's own size and location. What I am trying to do is to place a number of FixtureComponent vertically in my JFrame as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            main frame = new main();
            FixtureComponent comPanel = new FixtureComponent();

            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                frame.getContentPane().add(comPanel);
            }
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

The problem I am getting is when I run the above code, I get a single FixtureComponent placed at the top of the JFrame instead of getting 20 FixtureComponents placed vertically above each other.

And I would like to also know in case of that I successfully got the above code to work, how to add a scroll bar to scroll across the FixtureComponent?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and add a `JScrollPane` to the frame, setting the `JScrollPane` context to the content you need scrolling, in the example below this is a `JPanel` named `container`.

Add your `FixtureComponent` objects to `container`, and boom. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main frame = new Main();

            JPanel container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(container);
            scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 1000));

            for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                FixtureComponent fixture = new FixtureComponent();
                container.add(fixture);
            }

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(scroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i get a multiple FixtureComponents. However they stretch in size as the frame stretches. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: You'll need to do container.setMaximum(new Dimension(width, height)) - If I answered your question please mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: Still the same :/ Look here: http://s21.postimg.org/is91e97ef/Screen_Shot_2015_04_21_at_6_37_30_PM.png

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Have you tried `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT))` on your components within the `FixtureComponent`? I don't know what you're trying to achieve. Perhaps make a mock-up image.